# Error InvalidUri when upload file to Azure File Share

Tags: c#, azure-files

I was given the address like following to upload file to Azure File Share using Shared Access Signature(SAS)

https://myaccount.file.core.windows.net/xxxxx?sv=2020-08-04&ss=bfqt&srt=so&sp=rwdlacupitfx&se=2022-12-30T18:11:32Z&st=2021-12-12T10:11:32Z&spr=https&sig=signature

This is my test program

```
using Azure.Storage.Files.Shares;

public async Task TestAsync()
{
    var sas = @"https://myaccount.file.core.windows.net/xxxxx?sv=2020-08-04&ss=bfqt&srt=so&sp=rwdlacupitfx&se=2022-12-30T18:11:32Z&st=2021-12-12T10:11:32Z&spr=https&sig=signature";
    var localfile = @"C:\Test\local.txt";
    
    var client = new ShareFileClient(new Uri(sas));
    using (var stream = new FileStream(localfile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        var response = await client.UploadAsync(stream);
    }
}
```

The program throw RequestFailedException with following error:

```
Status: 400 (The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server.)
ErrorCode: InvalidUri

Additional Information:
UriPath: /xxxxx
```

My question is what this error mean, is it anything wrong in my test code?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-requests-to-azure-storage?redirectedfrom=MSDNhttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-requests-to-azure-storage?redirectedfrom=MSDN) uploading with SAS is not possible as it requires authentication to do so. Even though we try having the code correctly it still throws `Authentication information is not given in the correct format. Check the value of the Authorization header` exception. An alternative way is to use a connection string which of working fine when we try reproducing from our end.

Here is the code

```
static async Task Main(string[] args) {
  CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("<YOUR CONNECTION STRING>");

  CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();

  CloudFileShare share = fileClient.GetShareReference("<YOUR FILE SHARE>");

  if (await share.ExistsAsync()) {
    CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();

    CloudFile file = rootDir.GetFileReference("sample.txt");

    byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(@ "sample.txt");
    Stream fileStream = new MemoryStream(data);
    await file.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream);
  }
}
```

Here is the workaround using SAS that you can try:

```
using System.IO;
using Azure.Storage;
using Azure.Storage.Files.Shares;

public class SampleClass {
  public void Upload() {
    ///Get information from your Azure storage account and configure
    string accountName = "{Get the account name from the Azure portal site.}";
    string accessKey = "{Get the access key from the Azure portal site.}";
    Uri serverurl = new Uri(@ "{Get the URL from the Azure portal.}");

    ///Upload destination(azure side)
    string azureDirectoryPath = @ "{Destination(azure side)Specify the directory of}";
    string azureFileName = "{Specify the file name to save}";

    ///Upload target(Local side)
    string localDirectoryPath = @ "{Upload target(Local side)Specify the directory of}";
    string localFileName = "{Upload target(Local side)Specify the file name of}";

    //SSL communication permission setting
    //If you don't do this, SSL(https)An error occurs in communication.
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

    try {
      //Preparing to connect to Azure: Setting connection information
      StorageSharedKeyCredential credential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accessKey);

      //Connect to Azure
      ShareClient share = new ShareClient(serverurl, credential);

      ShareDirectoryClient directory = share.GetDirectoryClient(azureDirectoryPath);

      //Upload destination(azure side)Create if there is no folder in.
      directory.CreateIfNotExists();

      //Upload destination(azure side)Create a file instance in.
      ShareFileClient file = directory.GetFileClient(azureFileName);

      //Delete any file with the same name
      file.DeleteIfExists();

      //Open the Local file to be uploaded. It is easy to get binary information by opening it with FileStream type.
      FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(Path.Combine(localDirectoryPath, localFileName));

      //Upload destination(azure side)Inject binary information into a file instance
      file.Create(stream.Length);
      file.UploadRange(new Azure.HttpRange(0, stream.Length), stream);

      //Free local files
      stream.Dispose();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

**REFERENCE:**
[How to programmatically upload files to Azure Storage (File Share)](https://sourceexample.com/how-to-programmatically-upload-files-to-azure-storage-%28file-share%29-de8ba/)